# access values from multidimen array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi I have an array that i created using `push` like this

```
arr.push(h, s.power)
```

PS: `h` and `s.power` both are variables but depends on condition I applied

which ends up something like this

```
[22,"0.014",22,"0.01",22,"0.01",22,"0.082",22,"0.0002",22,"0.02822",22,"0.0042822",22,"0.041662",21,"0.0042822",21,"0.11107"]
```

but now I want to create new array for each new value like `22, 21` but I can not access it with  many combinations I tried such as `arr[22]`, with `arr.map`

Comment: I don't understand your question yet. Can you elaborate on it? What new array do you want to get?

Comment: *now I want to create new array for each new value like 22, 21* - can you elaborate this a bit ? Could you show the desired output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using a `Hash` instead. See [ruby hash documentation here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html).

So instead of pushing `h` and `s.power` into an array, you would add them to the hash like this:

```
my_hash[h] ||= []
my_hash[h].push(s.power)
```

The first line makes sure you have an array in the hash for the latest value of `h`. The second adds `s.power` to that array.

If you run this code repeatedly, you will end up with one array for each unique value of `h` which you can access like this:

```
my_hash[22] # <= returns the array of s.power values for h=22
my_hash[21] # <= returns the array of s.power values for h=21
```

If I understand your question correctly, this should be a clean way to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks this is perfectly what I wanted